# How to monitor QThread

Tags: c++, qt5, monitoring, qthread, qcoreapplication

I am working on Qt application. There I would like to have worker thread doing some activities in background and I would like main thread to control it, restarting worker thread if it dies for some reason.
I have seen finished() signal emitted by the thread so I guess I could connect slot to it.

Is that the recommended way? If not, how could I achieve that?

If I use finished() signal how can I know difference between normal termination and error?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether you had an error or you had the process finished, simply create two signals, not one, and two slots, not one.

In the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) you have an example there, with a connection to handle the result:

```
connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::resultReady, this, &MyObject::handleResults);
```

you're here connecting the signal `resultReady` with whatever method that handles the result. You create another one exactly like this, but with an error signal, and an error handler.

```
connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::errorThrown, this, &MyObject::handleErrors);
```

Of course, another option is to simply pass a parameter with your signals/slots. It's a function call, and if you put some `enum` with that for the status or some `int`, that'll do.

Comment: But how can I know if thread has an error and it dies? does it emit signal or something similar ?

Comment: @RuLoViC There's nothing I know of that "kills" a thread without killing your whole program. About exceptions, you have to handle them in your thread and pass them to the main thread. There are many ways to do this, such as `std::promise`. Qt also has its own implementation of promise and future I think. What I mentioned in the answer should also work.